# Filter pattern for cloud watch log group using aws-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to fetch the cloud watch(log group) logs based upon a filter. On my `yaml` file, I've given the filter pattern as `FilterPattern: "Success response"`. So after deploying the lambda function, it throws an error saying - `Invalid Subscription filter pattern(Service:cloudWatchLogs, StatusCode: 400,...`

The log looks like this -

```
{"info":"xxxxx", "message": "Success response","timeStamp": "2022-11-28 11:14 44:12", ......}
```

I want all the logs which has the word "Success response".

Note: I'm using Subscription filters with AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
FilterPattern: '{ $.message = "Success response" }'
```

Your logs are JSON formatted so `$` will let you access the parsed version.

`$.message` will return the message field and the filter checks if it is equal to the string you provided.

If you want to filter for a generic pattern you can use this:

```
'{ $.message = "response -*" }'
```

Comment: Also, I have a similar log with long and dynamic message value. "message": "response - AVN000........". After "response -" the value might change for each log. How can I write filter pattern for this?

Comment: You can use a wildcard like this:

{ $.message = "response -*" }

Comment: Hi I've posted another question filter pattern. Could you please check.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74995839/double-quotes-are-not-getting-added-on-filterpattern-aws-subscription-filter/74996040#74996040